# How to get the action name from which the user redirected to the current action in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two actions named 'abc' and 'def' in Home `Controller`. The action 'abc' returns RedirectToAction("def"). So can I get the name of the action in 'def' from which the `Redirect`ion triggered.

```
public ActionResult abc()
{
    //Some code
    return RedirectToAction("def");
}

public ActionResult def()
{
    //Some code
    string str = "You have been redirected from action 'abc'";
    return Content(str);
}
```

How can I get this name abc in the action def ?

Comment: **[Did you find it useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18122007/2015869)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the referring URL or the `Request.ServerVariables` dictionary, something like `Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]`

Answer (score 1):

### **You should not use URLReferrer. Why?**

Because `Request.UrlReferrer` it is not 100% correct way as there are many ways that `URLReferrer` can be blocked by security software/Antivirus, Firewall, Proxy program. `URLReferrer` will be null in Pop Ups. That's the reason I can't use `URLReferrer` to check from where this page is opened up.

### **So, What's the best way ?**

```
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Comment: Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] is NOT the same as URLReferrer. UrlReferrer tells you the url of the previous page, where you came from to get to the current page. The code above tells you the route values for the currently requested page.